# (Windows 7) Does disabling defragsvc completely disable defrags?

Tags: windows-7, filesystems, ntfs

Did several searches and it was surprisingly hard to find a straight answer (most of the search results were quasi-academic debate on "should solid-state disks be defragged"). My computer has a solid-state disk and therefore will never need a defrag (actually defrags can decrease the lifespan of a solid-state disk).

So I've been looking for any way to disable defrags and I disabled defragsvc. Is there anything else I need to disable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As quoted by [this](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/disable-defragmentation-ssd) website, windows 7 allegedly turns off disk defragment on ssds by default - even if this weren't true, disabling the disk defragment service would also stop the operation from running. So no, you shouldn't need to disable anything else.